# Transparently managing per-request transactions in Java-EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb

I'm developing a JEE application where each request done to "facade" beans should run a single transaction.

Basicly, in each method, I could do it like this:

```
@Override
public void updateSalaries(float factor)
{
    initializeTransaction();
    // Actual business code...
    commitTransaction();
}
```

Where ùpdateSalaries()`is a method invoked by the client, and where`initializeTransaction()`and`commitTransaction()` respectively take care of getting/starting/committing/rolling back (if necessary) the transaction.

Unfortunately, the transaction management should be more transparent: something developers should not care about when writing business methods.

Therefore, some way to "decorate" these business methods would be nice, but I can't think of a possible way to do that.

Another possible solution I thought of would be to handle it in a central `DataAccessBean` class, where I would start the transaction on `@PostConstruct` and commit it on `@PreDestroy`:

```
@Stateless
public class DataAccessBean implements IDataAccessBean
{
    @PostConstruct
    public void initializeTransaction() { /* ... */ }

    @PreDestroy
    public void endTransaction() { /* ... */ }

    @Override
    public <T implements Serializable> T getObjectById(
        Class<T> objectType, Object key) { /* ... */ }

    @Override
    public void saveObject(Serializable object) { /* ... */ }
}
```

I'm not sure though, if I can rely on that mechanism. An important question would also be, what type of bean I'd need: I doubt a stateful bean would be suitable as the transaction is per-request and not per-session. Maybe a stateless bean would be a good option, but AFAIK a stateless bean might not be destroyed when a request completes (if it resides in a stateless bean pool).

Two little constraints:

- The solution should not depend on a particular non-standard framework or JEE-server
- The solution should be compatible with JEE 6 and JEE 7

Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is addressed by Java Transaction API (JTA). From the JEE6 Tutorial (Part VIII - Chapter 42):

> The Java Transaction API (JTA) allows applications to access transactions in amanner that is
>   independent of speciic implementations. JTA speciies standard Java interfaces between a
>   transactionmanager and the parties involved in a distributed transaction system: the
>   transactional application, the Java EE server, and themanager that controls access to the shared
>   resources afected by the transactions.

You want to use the Container-Managed Transaction. In this strategy you just need decorate the beans/methods with the appropriate transaction attribute i.e.:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW) 
public void myMethod() {
...
}
```

The design of your service layer must carefully address the transaction life cycle in case your have services of services (nested service calls).